# Async databinding of image, causes cross thread exception

Tags: wpf, data-binding, asynchronous, datagridview, bitmapsource

I have a problem, with my WPF application.
I'm trying to databind an image field, in my gridview, with the image property from my viewmodel.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image, IsAsync=True}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This is no problem, if I don't use IsAsync.
However, I would like to do it async, as it's a lot of images to load, and it needs to load them from a webservice.

The code for the Image property is this, which just calls a handler dll, that calls a webservice.

```
    public BitmapSource Image
    {
        get { return image ?? (image = ImageHandler.GetDefaultImages(new[] {ItemNumber},160,160)[0].BitmapSource()); }
    }
```

But, as soon as I add the IsAsync=true, I get the following exception, once the form has loaded:

`The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

I am quite new to WPF, and I kind of assumed, that it handled the threading itself, when async was set to true. Do I need to somehow invoke, in the databinding?
If so, how on earth do I do this?

Comment: Can you add the code of your Image property ?

Comment: `BitmapSource` is derived from `Freezable`. If you don't intend to change the bitmap after it was created, you can simply `Freeze` it. Then any thread can access it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IsAsync` means that the bound property will be accessed from another thread, so make sure that whatever you're creating can then be used in a cross-thread manner. The final step of the binding will always occur on the main thread.

Almost all classes in WPF inherit from `DispatcherObject`, which basically 'links' an object to the current thread when it's created. The `BitmapSource` in your code is created on another thread and then cannot be used on the main UI thread.

However, `BitmapSource` inherits from `Freezable`: simply call the [`Freeze`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx) method on your `BitmapSource` before returning, to make it immutable and usable from any thread.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you access the image on separate thread and don't use IsAsync. Something like

```
public BitmapSource Image
    {
        get 
        { 
            return image ?? (Task.Factory.StartNew(() => image = ImageHandler.GetDefaultImages(new[] { ItemNumber }, 160, 160)[0].BitmapSource());) 
        }
    }
```